# HTML multiple choice quiz

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an HTML quiz recently, which is a page shown before a company page we use in my department. If the user answers correctly, then he can get the link to the page he needs to work.

However, when he answers wrongly, he gets a message and he can answer again, but the "Wrong Answer" that he got previously is still shown. That is what i don't want to happen.

The code of the quiz.js file is shown below. Also i post the HTML code of the answer section.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{    
    $("#results").click(function() {                    
        if (!$("input[@name=q1]:checked").val()) 
        {            
            alert("You're not done yet!");        
        }        
        else 
        {            
            var cat1name = "1";                         
            var cat11name = "None";            
            var cat1 = ($("input[@name=q1]:checked").val() != "b"); // correct answer
            var cat11 = (!cat1); var categories = [];                      
            if (cat1) { categories.push(cat1name) };                            
            if (cat11) { categories.push(cat11name) };                        

            var catStr = 'You answered the following questions incorrectly: ' + categories.join(', ') + '';                     
            $("#categorylist").text(catStr);                        
            $("#categorylist").show("slow");            

            if (cat1) { $("#category1").show("slow"); };            

            if (cat11) { $("#category11").show("slow"); };
            { $("#closing").show("slow"); };
        }
    });
});      

<div id="results">            
    Answer      
</div>                

<div id="category1">            
    <p>              
        <strong>Wrong answer!</strong>
    </p>        
</div>        

<div id="category11">         
    <p>You answered correctly!</p>
    <p><a href="somelink</a></p>        
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the corresponding HTML? I don't see any `input` or `#categorylist` there.

Comment: `<a href="somelink</a>` ? Wrong HTML Should be `<a href="somelink">link</a>` and you're missign the `input` in your HTML. Strange I have to say it, but if I were you I'd post the (really) necessary code in order to get help...

Comment: Can you explain what is your problem statement exactly here?

Comment: can you make a fiddle or post the actual quiz code?